# When $M$ is closed $M^\perp$ is one-dimensional vector space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $M=\{ x: Lx=0\}$, where $L$ is continuous linear functional on $H$ (Hilbert Space). Prove that $M^\perp$ is vector space of one-dimensional unless $M= H$.

I know $M$ is closed so that $M^\perp$ is complement of $M$ union $\{0\}$. But i am unable to see how it is span by only one basis.

Could anyone please help me.

Comment: I think you meant "unless $\;M=H\;$ "...

Comment: o sorry, you are right.. i will edit it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $u,v\ne 0$ and $u,v\perp M$. By this, it follows that $Lu\ne 0$ and $Lv\ne 0$. 
By norming them: $u_1:=\displaystyle\frac1{Lu}u,\ \ v_1:=\frac1{Lv}v$, we get $Lu_1=1=Lv_1$.

But then $u_1-v_1\in M$, however $u_1-v_1$ is still $\perp M$, leading to $u_1=v_1$.

Comment: Or, without norming: $Lv\cdot u-Lu\cdot v\ \in\ M\cap M^\perp=\{0\}$.